# How to parse arrays which vary between data sets?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following data set:

File1:

```
<Molecular Orbital Primitive Coefficients>
<MO Number>
1
</MO Number>
 4.224609607748e+00  4.085857782359e+00  1.273383604708e+00 -6.802974691818e-03
 9.099528133406e-03  6.867550219273e-03  5.859231188647e-03  3.684441849425e-03
 5.836775773317e-04 -2.316776085880e-16 -1.456850991492e-16 -2.307897076406e-17
 4.140895678156e-03  2.603906355541e-03  4.125025757803e-04 -1.739011495381e-03
-1.681896173898e-03 -5.241735641835e-04 -1.739011375813e-03 -1.681896058258e-03
-5.241735281434e-04
<MO Number>
2
</MO Number>
-9.785273892788e-01 -9.463889258321e-01 -2.949481372149e-01 -1.974411643609e-01
 2.640935048539e-01  1.993153249903e-01  2.392564397119e-01  1.504508715968e-01
 2.383394930083e-02  8.865383702284e-16  5.574791243465e-16  8.831407252698e-17
 1.690897356483e-01  1.063281646128e-01  1.684417017817e-02  4.608108515392e-02
 4.456761845182e-02  1.388977974599e-02  4.608108208174e-02  4.456761548054e-02
 1.388977881997e-02
</Molecular Orbital Primitive Coefficients>
```

File2:

```
<Molecular Orbital Primitive Coefficients>
<MO Number>
1
</MO Number>
 3.299451113326e-02  6.087754902119e-02  9.880244651376e-02  1.066781206974e-01
 6.773109582562e-02  1.104778461514e-02 -2.156994392623e-02  3.071021124268e-17
 1.072251279194e-16 -1.396334606969e-02 -2.002731618626e-16 -9.993341885751e-17
<MO Number>
2
</MO Number>
-2.009498358678e-04 -3.707687449719e-04 -6.017466156746e-04 -9.474065009358e-02
 3.917924760214e-01 -1.299844008310e-01  1.579980866207e-01 -2.827902468319e-15
 1.152587596877e-15 -2.310895197449e-01  2.213502483059e-15 -1.048685827923e-15
<MO Number>
 3
</MO Number>
-1.763944008217e-17 -3.254619757728e-17 -5.282150804455e-17 -3.109320915001e-16
-9.633800372448e-16 -1.118676262789e-17 -1.336368133403e-15 -1.286598202313e+00
-1.412088253954e+00  2.299271905206e-15  1.305465570574e+00  1.432795875849e+00
 3.494418486873e-16 -1.710573251253e-01 -1.877416268172e-01 -7.134748738863e-16
</Molecular Orbital Primitive Coefficients>
```

This data set varies between files in the size of the array and the number of arrays (i.e, some file may have 70 arrays so 70 MO Numbers, while others have 10). I am trying to write a function that will parse the data between the MO Number headers into an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
def function3(start, end):
    """Read MO information."""
    config_found = False
    var = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == end:
            config_found = False
        elif config_found:
            i = line.rstrip()
            var.append(i)
        elif line.strip() == start:
            config_found = True
    var1 = [elem.strip() for elem in var]
    var2 = var1[1:-1]
    var3 = np.array([line.split() for line in var2])
    var3 = np.asarray([list(map(float, item)) for item in var3])
    return var3
m = {'start1':'1','end1':'2',
         'start2':'2','end2':''}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    v['monumber1']=function3(m['start1'],m['end1'])
    v['monumber2']=function3(m['start2'],m['end2'])
```

The problem with this is that I will need to set these variables 70 times for some files! Moreover, the start and end variables for the final array are not applicable to all files. Is there a different way to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: There's the possibility of regex and numpy...

Comment: Adding the `regex` and `numpy` tags might help!

Comment: Does your data source suggest any standards for reading this?  The use of <> and </> suggest a xml model. but only in a loose sense.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your comment. It's a .wfx file, if that helps...

Comment: http://aim.tkgristmill.com/wfxformat.html AIM Extended Wavefunction Files (.wfx files)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vinicius's comment, i tried something with regex, please have a look and see if it helps. Usually is is not recommended to used the read() method, but since your data is not too much in this example i used it.

```
import re

x = []
with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    x = re.findall(r'\d\.\d+e[-+]\d+', fh.read())

out = map(float, x)
```

hope this helps, based on your input the above worked for me. the output is as below for file2:

```
[0.03299451113326, 0.06087754902119, 0.09880244651376, 0.1066781206974, 0.06773109582562, 0.01104778461514, 0.02156994392623, 3.071021124268e-17, 1.072251279194e-16, 0.01396334606969, 2.002731618626e-16, 9.993341885751e-17, 0.0002009498358678, 0.0003707687449719, 0.0006017466156746, 0.09474065009358, 0.3917924760214, 0.129984400831, 0.1579980866207, 2.827902468319e-15, 1.152587596877e-15, 0.2310895197449, 2.213502483059e-15, 1.048685827923e-15, 1.763944008217e-17, 3.254619757728e-17, 5.282150804455e-17, 3.109320915001e-16, 9.633800372448e-16, 1.118676262789e-17, 1.336368133403e-15, 1.286598202313, 1.412088253954, 2.299271905206e-15, 1.305465570574, 1.432795875849, 3.494418486873e-16, 0.1710573251253, 0.1877416268172, 7.134748738863e-16]
```

Comment: Not exactly...there is other data in the file, so I need to use the headers to specifically parse each array into a separate variable. But thank you, nonetheless!

Comment: that is also possible using regex, will try to get the correct regex. are there no better headers than 1,2..70? can i use </MO Number>?
you are welcome